# How to generate JSON data for chart in Jbuilder with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, charts, jbuilder

I´m trying create a file for a FLOT chart with next data:

```
{
        'label': 'Clicks',
        'color': Colors.byName('purple-300'),
        data: [
        ['1', 40],
        ['2', 50],
        ['12', 135]]
}
```

How can I create the data section array in jBuilder?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]", including the links. We need to see your effort. Did you write code? If no, why not? If you did, tell us why it doesn't work, give us the minimum data to confirm the problem and your expected output. SO isn't a "write code for me site", it's a "help me fix my broken code" site. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is applicable.

Comment: sorry but my english is not good and I can hardly explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution:

```
`json.label "Clicks"
 json.color "purple-300"
 json.data @direccion.analiticas.map{|i| ["#{i.id}",i.total_clicks]}`
```

Result:

```
`{"label":"Clicks","color":"purple-300","data":[["1",24],["2",20],["3",42],["4",10],["5",1],["6",14]]}`
```

It´s a good star. To pass this result to a graph Flot need the result is between square brackets [ ] and I can not find how to do this.

The result should be:

`[{"label":"Clicks","color":"purple-300","data":[["1",24],["2",20],["3",42],["4",10],["5",1],["6",14]]}]`

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Final solution:

```
 json.array!(@direccion) do |direccion|
  json.label "Clicks"
  json.color "purple-300"
  json.data direccion.analiticas.map{|i| ["#{i.id}",i.total_clicks]}
end
```

Thanks for all.